# Angular + Capacitor: Swift Compiler Warning and Capacitor Keyboard not working

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsb7.png)

I have set up my Angular app as Android and right now im working on the iOS part. So far my App is working but the keyboard doesn't show.

My Pods are installed correctly running on version "1.11.2"
I use Capacitor 3.2.4, cap/ios 3.2.4 and cap/keyboard 1.0.2

.../angular-mobile/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/Capacitor.h:15:1: Umbrella header for module 'Capacitor' does not include header 'CAPBridgeViewController+CDVScreenOrientationDelegate.h'

Comment: are you testing on real device or on a simulator?

Comment: Running on a Simulator

Comment: On the simulator menu check I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard. Should not be checked to let the software keyboard to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a harmless warning, but has been fixed, won't appear on next `@capacitor/ios` release.

As you are testing on the simulator, make sure that `Connect Hardware Keyboard` is not checked on the simulator menu (I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard)

If it's checked the software keyboard doesn't appear because it expects you to type from the computer's keyboard.